# MySQL: Add two columns when one or both may be null

Tags: mysql, sql

How can I add column a+b together when both may be null and null should be treated as zero?

Comment: Have you tried this yourself? Where is your code?

Comment: oh yeah you know @Chad, no, I surely didn't even try to add a+b AS c, I just came here because it's fun to ask... sorry couldn't resist ;) and yes, of course I tried!

Comment: My point was that people are more willing to help when they can see that you have attempted something. The only way to know that is if you post your code that you have tried and didn't work.

Comment: sure, but the "code" for adding two columns together is like "SELECT a+b AS c FROM table" so that's pretty pointless IMHO :)

Comment: @RaphaelJeger: It's not pointless because it shows us that you've actually tried something and have some idea what you're talking about.

Comment: I googled, believe it or not

Answer (score 8, accepted):

you can use `COALESCE()`

```
COALESCE(a, 0) + COALESCE(b, 0)
```

or `IFNULL()`

```
IFNULL(a, 0) + IFNULL(b, 0)
```

Answer (score 1):

Substitute a+b by IFNULL(a,0)+IFNULL(b,0) in your DDL/DML.
Well this is from MySQL's perspective.